# Match anything that is not a-z or A-Z or & followed by a number

Tags: regex

Does anyone know how to make a regex that will match if it contains anything other than normal characters or the & symbol but only IF it is followed by one number?

Basically it shouldn’t match if the word contains normal characters, and/or the & symbol followed by one number

Example of words that should not be matched: 
`&9Hello` `&1Hey&2You`

But it should match if it contains a different symbol, or number(s) without & symbol

Example of words that should be matched:
`@3Hello` `3Hello` `_Hey5` `&12Hello` `&Hello` `&1Hello@&£3`

Would help me a lot if someone knows how to make a regex for this or explain how I could make it work!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend editing your post to use backticks and quotes to delimit your code from your text. It's somewhat difficult to follow your requirements as it stands. Thank you!

Comment: Your request is not clear enough. Please use punctuation, especially commas, in your sentences so no misunderstanding can occur. Eg., this part is confusing: "… *that matches anything that is not a-z or A-Z or & followed by a number* …" Regards

Comment: You could try this `(^([^&]|[&]{2,})[&\w\d]*)` let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, I tried your regex but it’s not what I’m looking for, I appreciate your time and effort though! I edited the post so I hope it’s less confusing now!

Comment: @jerry After the examples, it seems like you're trying to combine several regexes into one. Hello and &1Hello@&£3 do not match the description. Are these mistakes? &1Hello@&£3 meets the not hit rule, so it can't meet the hit rule at the same time unless there are additional conditions for a regex that you don't mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the question not very clearly. If I understand correctly, I give an example in JavaScript.

EDIT:

**The following solves the problem assuming that the words 'Hello' and '&1Hello@&£3' have been incorrectly assigned by examples as indicated by the verbal description of the question.**

```js
var r=/^((?![A-Za-z&][0-9])|([A-Za-z&][0-9]{2})).*$/;

// not match
console.log(r.test('&9Hello')); 
console.log(r.test('&1Hey&2You')); 

// match
console.log(r.test('@3Hello'));
console.log(r.test('3Hello'));
console.log(r.test('_Hey5'));
console.log(r.test('&12Hello')); 
console.log(r.test('&Hello'));

// Examples given incorrectly
console.log(r.test('&1Hello@&£3'));  // not match
console.log(r.test('Hello'));        // match
```

**EDIT: The answer concerns examples you gave before editing your post.**

```js
var r=/^(?![A-Za-z&][0-9]).*$/;
console.log(r.test('3Hello'));
console.log(r.test('&&Hello'));
console.log(r.test('3&Hello'));
console.log(r.test('&3Hello'));
```

Explanation:

```
^$ start and end regex
() group elements
?! not containing
[A-Za-z&] one from range characters
[0-9] one from digit
.* any number of any characters

| or
{2} exactly 2
```

Comment: Hey, sorry about that! I tried to make it as clear as possible. It doesn’t match ```&1Hello``` which is good but if I put anything that shouldn’t be allowed after that it doesn’t match it, like: ```&1Hello@&/£```

Comment: @jerry It still seems unclear. The description says about A-Za-z0-9& preceding exactly one number and in the example you give the word Hello.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help I really appreciate it! I have removed ```Hello``` however ```&1Hello@&£3``` was not a mistake. I want it to match whenever it contains special characters or symbols excluding & (but only if this symbol is followed by a number) your regex works but like you said it doesn’t match ```&1Hello@&£3``` is it not possible to match this because it already contains ```&1Hello```?

Comment: @jerry Exactly. This word cannot be matched because it is already found to be mismatched, i.e. it has a capital or lowercase letter or & and one number at the beginning of the word. You would have to define additional rules that specify which strings go through and which ones don't.